# Debian caches ping request

Tags: shell, debian

I have a shellscript which pings a domain and echoes out failed or ok
the problem is that debian somehow caches the ping request and always ping the same domain even if i change it in the shellscript.

```
#!/bin/sh

# -q quiet
# -c nb of pings to perform

ping -c5 google.com

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "ok"
else
        echo "failed"
fi
```

Edit:

Current Output:

```
PING germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from germandeathsystem.de (193.25.100.197): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
```

Expected Output:

```
PING google.com (172.217.16.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=5.45 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=5.59 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.78): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=5.49 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.78): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=5.50 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.78): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=5.46 ms
```

Why does it still ping germandeathsystem.de and not google.com?

Comment: Can you please add the output you get and the output you expect to your post?

Comment: Sure just added it

Comment: Are you really really certain that you saved the shell script before running that? Maybe `echo` the domain you're pinging, or use `set -x` at the top of the script to see what commands get run

Comment: Okay so the strange thing is i tried to get to the else statement by using some non existing domain e.g googleddddddddddddddddddd.com. If i just ping that in the terminal it pings germandeathsystem.de again which is the server im pinging form

Comment: Are you sure that your DNS resolver does return you a failure for non-existing domains? Maybe all domain names get resolved, for example for a search engine like T-Systems "Navigationshelfer" or whatever it is called. Maybe investigate using `dig` that you receive `NXDOMAIN` for non-existing domains.

Comment: You have some problem with your resolver.

Comment: Ok so its definitely a problem with my resolve with ping there this strange return but with nslookup it perfectly works fine